# Can I see things that I've said in chat that have been starred?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, chat-stars

I was reviewing the star on chat.SE list this morning and I noticed that quite a few of the items on the list were mine.  I was curious as to how often people enjoy the things I post there enough to star them, but I can't seem to find statistics about this anywhere.  Mana told me that no such feature exists.  (the best we could come up with is [a list of things I've linked to, with the starred items at the top.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=http&User=27326&sort=stars))

So here's my request - can I filter/search the chat history for **things I've said** that **other people have starred**?

Comment: Always wanted this myself.

Comment: Interesting. It probably isnt hard to do... One for next week, maybe

Comment: +1 Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: @GnomeSlice: Presumably you didn't think of that because most of the Stars list is things that you've said taken out of context anyway.

Comment: @MarcGravell Did this ever get done?

Comment: Was just wondering this myself after getting a "Talkative" badge.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Just found this question for the same reason :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alright alright alright. It's an ego thing really, but I can't deny to sometimes be curious about that myself :)

The room's "stars" info page now has three subfilters; I've also clarified the wordings. They are "all" (the default), "starred by me", and "posted by me".

Comment: tested at Whiteboard, it's there indeed (`http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/21/the-whiteboard?tab=stars&filter=mymessages`). +1 for giving my ego a pleasant massage :)