# How do I check my progress on the Outspoken badge?

Tags: discussion, badges

All the [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) seem easy to check on [data.stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Except one, **Outspoken**.

> Posted 10 messages in chat that were starred by 10 different users

Is it possible to check my progress on this badge, and if so how?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114673/175002

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Chat statistics aren't available on data.stackexchange so you can't use it to track it.  As far as I know there's no easy/automated way to check on chat-related stats.

Answer (score 9):

Unless they build some badge progress indicator for this (which is unlikely), you'll never be able to check the status. Chat stars are kind of like upvotes: anonymous. There is no way (and probably never will be a way) to check *who* has starred any of your messages, so there's no way to figure out your progress.

Comment: But the badge requirement is "starred by 10 different users". So how would the "different users" criterion be checked if the users who starred the comments are not kept track of?

Comment: It's meant as *you*, the user, cannot track that.