# A badge to show quality not popularity

Tags: discussion, badge-request

Ok so this may not be the best sign of quality, but that's half of why I'm posting it up.

This was inspired by a meta post I can no longer find about why a post was closed, as well as seeing some posts around my [local stackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) site

The idea I had was a badge for having your question linked by 10, 25, 50 other questions, and perhaps with a requirement of a certain amount of upvotes too. This is supposed to indicate that question is good reference post and is valuable to the community.

Thoughts? Ideas? Improvements? Rotten fruit to throw?

<sub>Second badge request, split off [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146179/175002)</sub>

Comment: I like the first one, but as far as the second, I'm not a huge fan of adding time-based badges. I also don't see how it really encourages any good behavior.

Comment: I agree with @animuson; I like the general idea of the first idea, but I'm not sure the second really encourages any particular good behavior.

Comment: Perhaps this should be split into two questions, as these are two separate badges.

Comment: Maybe as a bonus for asking interesting / difficult questions @animuson? Anything that encourages more people to not ask the [same question time and again](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql_parameter+resource+parameter+boolean+given&submit=search) ought to be good.

Comment: The first badge should only be awarded if the person who linked the question isn't the questioner itself (otherwise it's very easy collecting badges).

Comment: +1 That's a nice metric, similar to citation index in academia.

Comment: Could we mock up results on [data.stackexchange](http://data.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I don't see this as a really good metric of "quality". It can just (or even at least) as easily be a indicator of the first instance of a persistent beginner's issue. Now those are *useful* but that doesn't make them *good*.

Comment: @dmckee how can something useful not be good? I'm it's that useful but poorly written someone will edit into shape from my experiences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thinking over this, the "linked *x* times" thing just doesn't work out well. As Chichiray mentioned in the comments, the user could just post the link on a bunch of questions, but so could *any* other user, maybe someone who answered the question. Also, *just* linking to another question doesn't necessarily mean it's even *related* to the topic where it was linked.

I like this idea, but I think it should be further limited. The first thing that comes to mind is "*x* number of questions closed as a duplicate of your question." Even then, it seems like it would be somewhat unreliable, as users can edit the duplicate notice. As well, many questions get closed as duplicates of questions which are also closed as duplicates.

Maybe they can use the same logic as the **Outspoken** badge for chat. The question has to be linked from *x* unique questions by *x* unique users. Seems fair?

Comment: And better than outspoken, you could hopefully [track your progress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145468/how-do-i-check-my-progress-on-the-outspoken-badge)! I like this idea a lot.

Comment: I think I may have spoke too soon. How about: *The question has to be linked from x unique questions by y unique users*. The Outspoken badge is quite hard to get as it is.

Comment: @Pureferret: You're also talking about Chat, though, which is a lot less active than the main site.

Comment: True, and I don't peruse SO as much as sci-fi which is much quieter. I wish I could see how often a post is linked already with data.stackexchange. Perhaps the y could be x/2? x/5? So we'd need 10 links from 5 users, 25 links from 12 users, and 50 links from 25 users? Or there about

Comment: Allowing more than one link from a single user only opens up the door for abuse. It needs to be one-to-one.

Comment: @animuson but with only two links per person it's not *that* much abuse is it?

Comment: If you go the complicated route like that, it's just plain not worth adding the badge (you open the door for overlap and make it very difficult to calculate which links are eligible for the count). Saying 10 links from 5 users implies that 4 users could link it 4 times then a fifth user could link it 6 times.

Comment: @animuson "10 links to a post by a user in another pose, each linker contributing no more than two each."  Does that imply the right thing?

Comment: The only problem with that is tracking it, it's incredibly hard. The badge isn't worth keeping track of it in that manner, IMO. My general philosophy: keep it simple-stupid.

Comment: Are there not stats on which question links where? If it's two hard to track my way, I'm sure your way would be just as good.