# Notify me when my chat message is starred

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-stars

Can we alter the chat system so that we are notified when our messages are starred?

I'd be happy with the normal style of notification (e.g. badge symbol on my Gravatar). The notification could either take me back to my starred message (much like a reply), or simply highlight the message in the side bar.

Note that a similar feature ([Can I see things that I've said in chat that have been starred?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114673/can-i-see-things-that-ive-said-in-chat-that-have-been-starred)) was implemented. This suggests to me:

- The community is interested in knowing that their messages have been starred by others.
- The developers will consider feature requests that are slightly egotistical in nature!

Comment: Starring isn't really something meant for you, though, is it? Their function is to draw *other* people's attention to the starred message.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Perhaps not. But I'm shallow enough to like to know when it's happened and I suspect I'm not alone in this? Perhaps I am...

Comment: Hunting for the [outspoken badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/138/outspoken) are we? :P

Comment: @Lix [Nope](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/138/outspoken?userid=192221) :-)

Comment: You have been starred ;)