# Check all starred message posted in chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, chat, chat-stars

I just earned [Talkative](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/884/talkative) badge in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Now, I want to know for which comment or message I got this badge ?
How would I know this?
 **Scenario:-** 1. I was chatting in a room and after some time, I earned Talkative badge. It means some one starred any message of mine. Now, I want to check which message of mine is starred?
2. I am in a room and reading whole transcript(chat) and found an interesting message of any one(Suppose user named "A") which is quite old and starred it. Now, how can the user "A" will check it? One thing, user "A" is active in many chat rooms.

**Note:-** I know we can see it under Starred post tab of all rooms. What I need is a list of all my starred messages (irrespective of room) in my profile. Can we have a tab named "My Starred Messages" along with "prefs", "recent", etc. in chat profile?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I see things that I've said in chat that have been starred?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114673/can-i-see-things-that-ive-said-in-chat-that-have-been-starred)

Comment: You got him wrong.. He wants all the starred messsage posted by him in any room